# I need help displaying data to an LCD using a PIC24EP512GU810 microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, lcd, mikroc, integrated

The LCD won't display anything no matter what I try.

I am trying to display data to an LCD using a PIC24EP512GU810 microcontroller. I know the bits are set to the correct pins for the LCD data because I have gotten characters to show up before with the same config. However now the characters don't seem to be showing up at all. I tried messing with delays to see if the LCD just needed more time to display the data values. I tried manually moving the cursor, adjusting the initialization settings for the LCD, commenting out the timer (so it doesn't interrupt a write to the LCD), and more. I know it is making it through the char arrays sent to it and even setting the right bits to the LCD. I have done everything I can think of to make this work, so I was hoping I could get some advise. The LCD I am using is a Hacktronix HDM16216L-7, not to be confused with Hacktronics god knows I've made that mistake. I should mention the LCD does work as I have checked it with a different board I have, so that is not the issue.

LCD_manual: [text](https://www.hantronix.com/files/data/1278554733char-comm.pdf)
LCD_DataSheet: [text](https://www.hantronix.com/files/data/127855473316216l7.pdf)

```
const unsigned int tm10ms = 2;
const unsigned int tm20ms = 4;
const unsigned int tm25ms = 5;
const unsigned int tm50ms = 10;
const unsigned int tm100ms = 20;
const unsigned int tm200ms = 40;
const unsigned int tm500ms = 100;
const unsigned int tm1000ms = 200;
const unsigned int tm2000ms = 400;
const unsigned int tm5000ms = 1000;
const unsigned int tm1min = 12000;
const unsigned int tm5min = 60000;
const unsigned long tm10min = 120000;
unsigned int count5ms = 1;
unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int ii = 0;
void SetLCDData(unsigned char chardata);
void LcdInit();
void LcdCmd(unsigned char cmd);
void LcdWrite(unsigned char *cmd);
unsigned char charData;
int countvar = 0;

void InitTimer1(){        //10ms
     T1CON         = 0x8020;
     T1IE_bit         = 1;
     T1IF_bit         = 0;
     IPC0         = IPC0 | 0x1000;
     PR1         = 10937;
}

void Timer1Interrupt() iv IVT_ADDR_T1INTERRUPT
{
  T1IF_bit     = 0;
  count5ms = 1;
}

void LcdInit()
{
    delay_ms(50);
    AN_AvgValues[idxSigBusFLT] = 0;       //corresponds to the R/W bit of the LCD
    LcdCmd(0x38);  //Set LCD Functionality
    LcdCmd(0x0e);  //LCD ON 1110      cursor on
    LcdCmd(0x01);  //clear the Display    0001
    LcdCmd(0x06);  //Entry Mode Set  0111  increment cursor no display shift
    LcdCmd(0x80);  //set the DD Ram address aka the location on the lcd which we will Display a character
}

void LcdCmd(unsigned char cmd)
{
     LCD_RS = 0;
     SetLCDData(cmd);
     delay_ms(1);
}

void LcdWrite(unsigned char *cmd)
{
     LCD_RS = 1;
     ii = 0;
     while (cmd[ii] != '~')
     {
        SetLCDData(cmd[ii]);
        delay_ms(100);
        LD_FAULT=~LD_FAULT;
        ii++;
     }
}

void SetLCDData(unsigned char charData)
{
      AN_AvgValues[idxSigBusFLT] = 0; //represents the R/W signal always 0
      LCD_D0 = charData.B0;
      LCD_D1 = charData.B1;
      LCD_D2 = charData.B2;
      LCD_D3 = charData.B3;
      LCD_D4 = charData.B4;
      LCD_D5 = charData.B5;
      LCD_D6 = charData.B6;
      LCD_D7 = charData.B7;
      LCD_EN = 1;
      delay_ms(1);
      LCD_EN = 0;
      delay_ms(50);
}


void main() {
     //PLL Config for 140MHz Fosc
     //Fosc = Fin*(M/(N1*N2)) --> 140MHz = 8*(70/4)
        PLLFBD = 68;             // PLL multiplier M=70
        CLKDIV = 0x0000;         // PLL prescaler N1=2, PLL postscaler N2=2
     
    //SET Analog bits and TRIS bits

    LcdInit();    // Initialize The LCD
    delay_ms(50);

    LcdWrite("test~");
    LcdCmd(0xc0);
    LcdWrite("BadApple~");
    //InitTimer1(); // Initialize Timer 1 for Period Interrupts
    while(1)
    {
       /*if (count5ms == 1)
       {
           count5ms = 0;
           count++;
           if (count%tm1000ms == 0)
           {
                LcdWrite("Bad Apple~");
           }
       } */
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the exact code you posted used to work, and now it doesn't? If so check your wiring, maybe something has come loose. If you've changed the code and now it doesn't work, revert back to the older version that did then see what you changed. You are using version control, right?

Comment: I lost the last version, or I would go back. I don't know what version control is, so probably not.

Comment: You should probably find out what version control is and start using it. There are many to choose from, but `git` is a popular choice, and there are lots of [tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control) online.